# Passing the translate value to the React component using react2angular

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

This is the component that I'm using:

```
<my-component
  data="vm.data"
></my-component>
```

I would like to pass it a translated string, but I get a syntax error:

```
<my-component
  data="vm.data"
  string="{{ 'TOP_FIVE' | translate }}" // throws error in browser console
></my-component>
```

How can I pass along the translated string value?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using angular-translate the best way is to inject the $translate service to your react2angular component and extend your react component with a function that return the translated string:

```
// INJECT SERVICE
angular
  .module("components", [])
  .component(
    "myComponent",
    react2angular(MyComponent), ["data"], ["$translate"])
  )

// REACT COMPONENT
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  translate = key => {
    return this.props.$translate.instant(key)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{this.translate('TOP_FIVE')}</p>
    )
  }
}
```